# INFORMATION_SCHEMA: can this be used to find all the same named columns in all tables in same database

Tags: sql, information-schema

I've been handed a new database with over 500 tables.  Can I use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to execute a query to list all the tables and identify those same named columns across all the tables within the database.  So essentially I want to have a list of all tables and identity those tables which have a commonly named column.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and the information_schema is not identical between the different vendors. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can `self-join` system view `information_schema.columns`:

```
select 
    ta.column_name,
    ta.table_name,  
    tb.table_name,
from information_schema.columns ta
inner join information_schema.columns tb 
    on  ta.column_name = tb.column_name 
    and ta.table_name != tb.table_name
order by 
    ta.column_name, 
    ta.table_name,
    tb.table_name
```

This will give you all the columns that are used in more than one table, with the corresponding table names.

If you just want the table names, then:

```
select ta.table_name,  tb.table_name
from information_schema.columns ta
inner join information_schema.columns tb 
    on  ta.column_name = tb.column_name 
    and ta.table_name != tb.table_name
group by ta.table_name,  tb.table_name
order by ta.table_name,  tb.table_name
```

Note: You probably want to add a filter on `table_schema` to limit the query to the schema(s) used in your application.

Comment: thanks but would I be able to gleam sizes (row counts) of tables from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA or would I have individually query each table?